# Python Memory Issue with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, memory, beautifulsoup

I've resolved this issue, but I'm wondering why it was caused in the first place. I used BeautifulSoup to identify this span from a webpage:

```
span = <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RestInfoReskin_lblRestName">Ally's Sizzlers</span>
```

I then assign this variable:

```
restaurant.name = span.contents
```

However on each loop this takes up a full 1 MB, and there's about 20,000 loops. Through trial and error I came upon this solution:

```
restaurant.name = str(span.contents)
```

Can you tell me why the former span.contents takes up so much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `str(span.contents)` is calling the `__str__` function inside the object `span.contents` and returning a smaller representation. You can use the [pympler](http://code.google.com/p/pympler/) to measure the memory consumption

Answer (score 1):

Old stuff, but just in case other people wonder: `span.contents` returns a reference to a `NavigableString` instance. There is a link between this instance and the DOM tree, so that as long as this instance is in use, the whole DOM tree cannot be released from memory by the garbage collector. Thus, as long as `restaurant.name` is not released from memory, the whole DOM tree is kept in memory.

Using `str(span.contents)` returns a string which is not linked with the DOM tree, so it does not prevent the DOM tree from being released from memory.