# Memory Error while using Requests and BeautifulSoup on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using requests and BeautifulSoup to parse Wikidata to build a Person object. I am able to do this successfully, however when doing it iteratively I run into the MemoryError below after creating ~3,000 Person objects.

```
MemoryError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TreeBuilder.py", line 11, in <module>
    ancestor = Person(next['id'])
  File "/home/ec2-user/Person.py", line 14, in __init__
    html = soup (data , 'lxml')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 325, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 399, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 324, in feed
    self.parser.feed(markup)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1242, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.feed
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1285, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.feed
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 855, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._getPushParserContext
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 871, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._createContext
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 528, in lxml.etree._ParserContext.__cinit__
SystemError: <class 'lxml.etree._ErrorLog'> returned a result with an error set
```

I have tried to catch the exception which doesn't work using the following;

```
try:
  data = requests.get (url).text
  html = soup(data, 'lxml')
except MemoryError:
  return None
```

This error doesn't occur on my local machine when running the program in Pycharm, just on my AWS EC2 server.

**UPDATE**

See code below. I have added `gc.collect()` after every 100 iterations, which has not seemed to have helped.

***Person.py***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

class Person:

    def __init__(self, id):
        url = 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/' + id
        data = requests.get (url).text
        html = soup (data , 'lxml')

        ### id ###
        self.id = id

        ### Name ###
        if html.find ("span" , {"class": "wikibase-title-label"}) != None:
            self.name = html.find ("span" , {"class": "wikibase-title-label"}).string
        else:
            self.name = ""

        ### Born ###
        self.birth = ""

        birth = html.find ("div" , {"id": "P569"})
        if birth != None:
            birth = birth.findAll ("div" , {"class": "wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})
            if len(birth) > 0:
                self.birth = birth[0].string

        ### Death ###
        self.death = ""

        death = html.find ("div" , {"id": "P570"})
        if death != None:
            death = death.findAll ("div" , {"class": "wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})
            if len(death) > 0:
                self.death = death[0].string

        #### Sex ####
        sex = html.find ("div" , {"id": "P21"})

        if sex != None:
            for item in sex.strings:
                if item == 'male' or item == 'female':
                    self.sex = item

        ### Mother ###
        self.mother = ""

        mother = html.find ("div" , {"id": "P25"})
        if mother != None:
            mother = mother.findAll ("div" , {"class": "wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})
            if len(mother) > 0:
                self.mother = {"name": mother[0].string , "id": mother[0].find ('a')['title']}

        ### Father ###
        self.father = ""

        father = html.find ("div" , {"id": "P22"})
        if father != None:
            father = father.findAll ("div" , {"class": "wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak"})
            if len(father) > 0:
                self.father = {"name": father[0].string , "id": father[0].find ('a')['title']}

        ### Children ###
        self.children = []
        x = html.find("div" , {"id": "P40"})
        if x != None:
            x = x.findAll("div" , {"class": "wikibase-statementview"})

            for i in x:
                a = i.find ('a')
                if a != None and a['title'][0] == 'Q':
                    self.children.append ({'name': a.string , 'id': a['title']})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + "\n\tBirth: " + self.birth + "\n\tDeath: " + self.death + "\n\n\tMother: " + \
               self.mother['name'] + "\n\tFather: " + self.father['name'] + "\n\n\tNumber of Children: " + \
               str(len(self.children))
```

***TreeBuilder.py***

```
from Person import Person
import gc, sys

file = open('ancestors.txt', 'w+')

ancestors = [{'name':'Charlemange', 'id':'Q3044'}]
all = [ancestors[0]['id']]
i = 1

while ancestors != []:
    next = ancestors.pop(0)
    ancestor = Person(next['id'])

    for child in ancestor.children:
        if child['id'] not in all:
            all.append(child['id'])
            ancestors.append(child)

    if ancestor.mother != "" and ancestor.mother['id'] not in all:
        all.append(ancestor.mother['id'])
        ancestors.append(ancestor.mother)

    if ancestor.father != "" and ancestor.father['id'] not in all:
        all.append(ancestor.father['id'])
        ancestors.append(ancestor.father)


    file.write(ancestor.id + "*" + ancestor.name + "*" + "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/" + ancestor.id + "*" + str(ancestor.birth) + "*" + str(ancestor.death) + "\n")

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print (ancestor.name + " (" + ancestor.id + ")" + " - " + str(len(all)) + " - " + str (len(ancestors)) + " - " + str (sys.getsizeof(all)))
        gc.collect()

    i += 1

file.close()
print("\nDone!")
```

Comment: How much RAM(EC2) you have?

Comment: Its a t2.micro with 1GB of Memory and 1 vCPU

Comment: did you check if you actually run out of memory?

Comment: I did actually run out of memory, but I don't know why. I am not storing any of the objects, they should be garbage collected after I am finished using them should they not?

Comment: but check if the data is stored in memory when you run it on your local pc (even with taskmgr or equivalent)

Comment: No it doesn't seem to be as bad. Pycharm is using 1.5 GB while running the program at 10,000 iterations. And it idles at ~ 700 MB, so it has only increased by about 800 MB since the program started.

Comment: Can you post example code?

Comment: @totalhack now posted

Answer (score 0):

The solution, however annoying, is to wrap all of your references to BS objects in a `str()` call. While it seems like you are storing a reference to just a bare string when doing `birth[0].string`, it turns out the references to BS objects just keep building in memory when you do that in a loop. Give it a shot, I just tried it with your code and the memory footprint stayed quite low.

Just make sure you catch all references, for example:

`self.children.append({'name': str(a.string), 'id': str(a['title'])})`

Edit: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089087/10682164) for a possible explanation of why BS ends up holding onto these references.

Comment: Do you know why they would keep references in memory?
I had changed the class into a function that returns a dictionary instead of creating an object and it seems to work fine, even with the BS objects not in strings.

Comment: Interesting. Mind posting your revised, working code? This might be a quirky problem with the BS library given that other people on SO have run into the same issue in unexpected circumstances.